# jQuery Onclick Function is Firing Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have some code and I want the code to add a `table row` with four `table cell`s every time I click a `button`. When I click it the first time, it adds one `row` just like it is supposed to. However, when I click it a second time, it adds two `row`s and then three `row`s and then four `row`s etc..

I am wondering why this is happening and how I can fix it. Code:

```js
var webnetPriceChange;
var cloneCorpPriceChange;
var cityBankPriceChange;
var herbmartPriceChange;
var digitalSystemsPriceChange;
var nationalAirlinesPriceChange;
var statePowerPriceChange;
var parklandPriceChange;
var priceSet;
var stocks = -1;
$(function() {
    // update color of totalMoney
    setInterval(function() {
        var totalMoney = parseInt($("#purchaseStockMoneyAfterPrice").text());
        if (totalMoney > 0) {
            $("#purchaseStockMoneyAfterPrice").css("color", "green");
        }
        else {
            $("#purchaseStockMoneyAfterPrice").css("color", "darkRed");
        } 
    }, 1);
    $("#purchaseStockButton").click(function() {
        stocks++;
        $("#purchaseStockSelect").val("Webnet");
        var webnetActivated = true;
        var cloneCorpActivated = false;
        var flipPurchaseStockAnimation = $("#purchaseStockBox");
        var entireTable = $("#entireTable");
        var webnetPrice = parseInt($("#webnetPrice").text());
        var cloneCorpPrice = parseInt($("#cloneCorpPrice").text());
        var money = parseInt($("#money").text());
        $("#purchaseStockMoneyAfterPrice").text(money);
        var totalMoney = parseInt($("#purchaseStockMoneyAfterPrice").text());
        $("#numberPurchaseStock").val("100");
        var numberPurchaseStock = $("#numberPurchaseStock").val();
        var cost;
        var moneyLeft;
        $("#flipBlueCardBox").hide();
        entireTable.animate({
            opacity: 0,
        }, 1000);
        flipPurchaseStockAnimation.animate({
            top: "+=200px"
        }, 0);
        flipPurchaseStockAnimation.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
        // change price upon changing stock
        $("#purchaseStockSelect").change(function() {
            var purchaseStockSelected = $("#purchaseStockSelect").val();
            if (purchaseStockSelected == "Webnet") {
                webnetActivated = true;
                cloneCorpActivated = false;
            }
            else if (purchaseStockSelected === "Clone Corp") {
                cloneCorpActivated = true;
                webnetActivated = false;
            }
        });
        setInterval(function() {
            var numberPurchaseStock = $("#numberPurchaseStock").val();
            if (webnetActivated === true) {
                cost = webnetPrice * numberPurchaseStock;
            }
            else if (cloneCorpActivated === true) {
                cost = cloneCorpPrice * numberPurchaseStock;
            }
            moneyLeft = totalMoney - cost;
            $("#purchaseStockPrice").text(cost);
            $("#purchaseStockMoneyAfterPrice").text(moneyLeft);
        }, 1);
        // update stocks table
        $("#numberPurchaseStockButton").click(function() {
            var totalMoney = parseInt($("#purchaseStockMoneyAfterPrice").text());
            if (totalMoney >= 0) {
                var flipPurchaseStockAnimation = $("#purchaseStockBox");
                var entireTable = $("#entireTable");
                var numberPurchaseStock = $("#numberPurchaseStock").val()
                var purchaseStockSelected = $("#purchaseStockSelect").val();
                if (purchaseStockSelected == "Webnet") {
                    priceSet = webnetPrice;
                }
                else if (purchaseStockSelected == "Clone Corp") {
                    priceSet = cloneCorpPrice;
                }
                $("#yourStockTableHeader").after('<tr><td id = "stockAmount' + stocks + '">' + numberPurchaseStock + '</td><td id = "stockType' + stocks + '">' + purchaseStockSelected + '</td><td id = "stockPurchaseCost' + stocks + '">' + cost + '</td><td id = "stockSellPrice' + stocks + '">' + priceSet + '</td></tr>');
                cost = 0;  
                entireTable.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 1000);
                flipPurchaseStockAnimation.animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 1000);
                $("#flipBlueCardBox").show();
                var webnetActivated = false;
                var cloneCorpActivated = false;
            }
            else {
                alert("You do not have enough money!");
            }
        });
    });
    // Creates animation after button click
    $("#flipABlueCard").click(function() {
        var flipABlueCardAnimation = $("#flipBlueCardBox");
        var entireTable = $("#entireTable");
        entireTable.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
        $("#purchaseStockBox").hide();
        flipABlueCardAnimation.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
    });
    // Sets the values after having clicked the button
    $("#numberBlueCardButton").click(function() {
        var numberBlueCardValue = $("#numberBlueCard").val();
        var entireTable = $("#entireTable");
        var flipABlueCardAnimation = $("#flipBlueCardBox");
        entireTable.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
        flipABlueCardAnimation.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
        $("#purchaseStockBox").show();
        if (numberBlueCardValue == 1) {
            webnetPriceChange = 12;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 10;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 17;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 5;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 2) {
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 12;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 20;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 15;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 10;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 3) {
            webnetPriceChange = 15;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 18;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 8;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 20;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 4) {
            webnetPriceChange = 9;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 9;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 14;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 19;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 5) {
            webnetPriceChange = 6;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 17;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 9;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 14;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 6) {
            webnetPriceChange = 16;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 12;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 22;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 16;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 7) {
            herbmartPriceChange = 10;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 12;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 19;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 16;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 8) {
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 15;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 17;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 11;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 15;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 9) {
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 14;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 11;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 13;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 17;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 10) {
            webnetPriceChange = 13;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 16;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 14;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 11;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 11) {
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 13;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 20;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 18;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 15;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 12) {
            webnetPriceChange = 8;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 11;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 19;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 11;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 13) {
            webnetPriceChange = 7;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 16;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 12;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 12;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 14) {
            webnetPriceChange = 11;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 13;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 16;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 21;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 15) {
            webnetPriceChange = 10;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 10;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 13;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 13;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 16) {
            herbmartPriceChange = 15;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 12;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 17;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 11;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 17) {
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 14;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 13;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 18;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 14;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 18) {
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 16;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 12;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 9;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 7;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 19) {
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 8;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 19;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 10;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 13;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 19) {
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 8;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 19;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 10;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 13;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 20) {
            cityBankPriceChange = 18;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            herbmartPriceChange = 17;
            $("#herbmartPrice").text(herbmartPriceChange);
            statePowerPriceChange = 21;
            $("#statePowerPrice").text(statePowerPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 8;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 21) {
            webnetPriceChange = 14;
            $("#webnetPrice").text(webnetPriceChange);
            digitalSystemsPriceChange = 15;
            $("#digitalSystemsPrice").text(digitalSystemsPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 6;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 9;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else if (numberBlueCardValue == 22) {
            cloneCorpPriceChange = 7;
            $("#cloneCorpPrice").text(cloneCorpPriceChange);
            cityBankPriceChange = 15;
            $("#cityBankPrice").text(cityBankPriceChange);
            nationalAirlinesPriceChange = 14;
            $("#nationalAirlinesPrice").text(nationalAirlinesPriceChange);
            parklandPriceChange = 18;
            $("#parklandPrice").text(parklandPriceChange);
        }
        else {
            alert("An invalid card number was entered");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
#entireTable {
    position: static;
    display: table;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    color: blanchedalmond;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
#yourStockTable {
    height: 280px;
}
#yourMoneyTable {
    height: 280px;
    width: 280px;
}
#moneyTab {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
th, td {
    border: 1.5px solid darkgray;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
}
#purchaseStockButton, #sellStockButton, #flipABlueCard, #flipANewsCard {
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1.5px solid darkgray;
}
#purchaseStockButton {
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
}
#sellStockButton {
    background-color: brown;
}
#flipABlueCard {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
#flipANewsCard {
    background-color: coral;
}
#purchaseStockButton:hover, #sellStockButton:hover, #flipABlueCard:hover, #flipANewsCard:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#flipBlueCardBox, #purchaseStockBox {
    opacity: 0;
}
#numberBlueCard {
    width: 40px;
}
#numberPurchaseStock {
    width: 65px;
}
#upArrowBlueCard:hover, #downArrowBlueCard:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#upArrowBlueCard, #downArrowBlueCard {
    font-size: 25px;
}
#numberBlueCardButton, #numberPurchaseStockButton {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1.5px solid darkgray;
}
#numberBlueCardButton:hover, #numberPurchaseStockButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}body {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
#entireTable {
    position: static;
    display: table;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    color: blanchedalmond;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
#yourStockTable {
    height: 280px;
}
#yourMoneyTable {
    height: 280px;
    width: 280px;
}
#moneyTab {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
th, td {
    border: 1.5px solid darkgray;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
}
#purchaseStockButton, #sellStockButton, #flipABlueCard, #flipANewsCard {
    width: 175px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1.5px solid darkgray;
}
#purchaseStockButton {
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
}
#sellStockButton {
    background-color: brown;
}
#flipABlueCard {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
#flipANewsCard {
    background-color: coral;
}
#purchaseStockButton:hover, #sellStockButton:hover, #flipABlueCard:hover, #flipANewsCard:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#flipBlueCardBox, #purchaseStockBox {
    opacity: 0;
}
#numberBlueCard {
    width: 40px;
}
#numberPurchaseStock {
    width: 65px;
}
#upArrowBlueCard:hover, #downArrowBlueCard:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#upArrowBlueCard, #downArrowBlueCard {
    font-size: 25px;
}
#numberBlueCardButton, #numberPurchaseStockButton {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1.5px solid darkgray;
}
#numberBlueCardButton:hover, #numberPurchaseStockButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon.ico">
        <title>Stock Market Board</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <center>
                <div id = "entireTable">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Stock</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Webnet</td>
                            <td id = "webnetPrice">11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Clone Corp</td>
                            <td id = "cloneCorpPrice">12</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>City Bank</td>
                            <td id = "cityBankPrice">15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Herbmart</td>
                            <td id = "herbmartPrice">14</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Digital Systems</td>
                            <td id = "digitalSystemsPrice">17</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>National Airlines</td>
                            <td id = "nationalAirlinesPrice">10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>State Power</td>
                            <td id = "statePowerPrice">16</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Parkland</td>
                            <td id = "parklandPrice">13</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id = "yourStockTable">
                        <tr id = "yourStockTableHeader">
                            <th>Shares</th>
                            <th>Stock</th>
                            <th>Cost</th>
                            <th>Stock Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id = "yourMoneyTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th id = "moneyTab">                           Money                              </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id = "money">10000</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br>
                    <button id = "purchaseStockButton">Purchase Stock</button>
                    <button id = "sellStockButton">Sell Stock</button>
                    <button id = "flipABlueCard" >Flip A Blue Card</button>
                    <button id = "flipANewsCard">Flip A News Card</button>
            </div>
                <div id = "flipBlueCardBox">
                    <h3 class = "title">Blue Card Number</h3>
                    <br>
                    <input id = "numberBlueCard" value = "1" type = "number" min = "1" max = "22"><br><br>
                    <button id = "numberBlueCardButton">Set</button>
                </div>
                <div id = "purchaseStockBox">
                    <h3 class = "title">Purchase Stock</h3><br>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Stock</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Cost</th>
                            <th>Money After Transaction</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select id = "purchaseStockSelect">
                                    <option value = "Webnet">WEB</option>
                                    <option value = "Clone Corp">CC</option>
                                    <option value = "City Bank">CTY</option>
                                    <option value = "Herbmart">H</option>
                                    <option value = "Digital Systems">DS</option>
                                    <option value = "National Airlines">NA</option>
                                    <option value = "State Power">SP</option>
                                    <option value = "Parkland">P</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input id = "numberPurchaseStock" type = "number" min = "100" value = "100" step = "100"></td>
                            <td id = "purchaseStockPrice">0</td>
                            <td id = "purchaseStockMoneyAfterPrice"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br>
                    <button id = "numberPurchaseStockButton">Set</button>
                </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S To view the code as it is supposed to be, do it in a full page result.
P.P.S To operate the program (to get it to create `rows`), press on the 'Purchase Stock' `button`.

Comment: That happen because you've nested events, you're attaching the events inside events, so everytime you click the event will be attched that what leads to multiple event attachement to the same element...

Comment: Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you've `nested` `event`s, you're attaching the `event`s inside `event`s, so every time you click a new `event` will be attached and that leads to multiple `event` attachment to the same `element`.

Try to avoid the `nested` `events` & pull out the `event`s, or use the `off()` to detach the `event` before attaching the new one using `on()`, like this:

```
$("#numberPurchaseStockButton").off('click').on('click', function() {
```

Instead of this:

```
$("#numberPurchaseStockButton").click(function() {
```

Hope this helps.